# How to run angular app with routes on NodeJs (Express)?

Tags: node.js, angular, express

It works good on apache server with htaccess settings, but how to make it works on NodeJs?

I have an Angular app with routes:

`.....

```
const appRoutes: Routes =[
    {path: 'main', component: MainComponent},
    {path: 'department', component: DepartmentComponent},
    {path: 'projects', component: ProjectsComponent},
    {path: 'results', component: ResultsComponent},
    {path: 'library', component: LibraryComponent},
    {path: 'enter', component: EnterComponent},
    {path: 'exit', component: ExitComponent},
    {path: 'admin', component: AdminComponent},
    {path: '**', redirectTo: '/main'}
];

@NgModule({
    imports:      [TreeModule, BrowserModule, FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule, HttpClientModule, RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes)]
```

.....,`

When i use an Apache server, i can make it works with a simple htaccess code (copied from wordpress pattern):

```
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
```

All routes works, i can type sitename.com/main or sitename.com/department or another path with routes - and get a corresponding page from corresponding Angular component: MainComponent, DepartmentComponent or any else.

But i can't make it works on NodeJs server. Only simple link sitename.com works - i recieve a main page, but sitename.com/main or sitename.com/department returns "Cannot GET /main" or "Cannot GET /department" error.

What should i do to make it works like on apache server?

Comment: You need to redirect all requests in the nodejs server with path `/*` to the index.html file for your frontend application.

Comment: @ImAtWar not working :-(  Wrote
`app.all('*', function(req, res) {
  res.redirect('/index.html');
});`

But it redirects everything to the main page: /main, /department, everythong else - all redirects to /main.